# What's the easiest way to add attribute to XML in a text box in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have XML in the following format that is entered either by hand or script into a text box:

```
<instructions>
  <step index="1">Do this</step>
  <step index="2">Do that</step>
</instructions>
```

I want to be able to click on a button to add an attribute to the instructions element so all the XML will remain intact, but the resulting XML in the text box would look like this:

```
<instructions iterations="3">
  <step index="1">Do this</step>
  <step index="2">Do that</step>
</instructions>
```

I was able to get the XML into an XmlDocument, but I'm having trouble adding the element and getting the results back into the text box.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the code I have so far based on the feedback:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(textBoxInstructions.Text);

var attr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("iterations");
attr.InnerText = "3";
string strNewXML = xmlDoc.InnerXml;

textBoxInstructions.Text = strNewXML;
```

However, the old is the same as the new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc .LoadXml(textBoxInstructions.Text); 

var attr = doc.CreateAttribute("iterations");
attr.InnerText = "3";
doc .Attributes.Append(attr);

 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
 doc.WriteTo(xw);
 yourTextBox.Text = sw.ToString();
```

For element

```
var xmlElement = doc.CreateElement("...");
xmlElement.SetAttribute("Name","Value");
```

Comment: That didn't add the attribute to the instructions element.  I can't see it anywhere in the XML.

Comment: The element <instructions> already exists so I don't want to create a new one do I?

Comment: I tried the first code, but the attribute was never added.  I debugged and doc is the same before and after the lines ran.

Comment: I tried to copy my code to the comments, but that failed.  I'll put it in a new post.

Comment: I want to save it back to the textbox - not an XML file.

Comment: It writes back the original XML - no attribute is written!

Comment: add this line     doc .Attributes.Append(attr);

Comment: That line gives a nullReferenceException.

Comment: I put the updated code in your post that allowed the attribute to be updated.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the following function on the click event of the button.

```
 public void populateNewXML()
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(textBoxInstructions.Text);
            var attr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("iterations");
            attr.InnerText = "3";
            xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("instructions")[0].Attributes.Append(attr);
            textBoxInstructions.Text = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
        }
```